# how to secure rest api exposed to different clients

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework

So I have a REST api that's used by two other applications - SPA app and mobile apps. I'm using CORS without any restrictions for allowed domains (for now) but when all gets to production I will have to set some restrictions. It looks like I should be allowing only traffic from the SPA app, but what about mobile applications? Is setting up communication between components and api exclusively via https enough? Both - the spa app and mobile apps can perform `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH` and `DELETE` operations.

Comment: what about using oauth2 authentication or an api key access with platform specific user-agent matching?

Comment: OAuth2 seems like a reasonable and standardized approach. I'll definitely have a look.